# How do you get batches of rows from Spark using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a Spark RDD of over 6 billion rows of data that I want to use to train a deep learning model, using train_on_batch. I can't fit all the rows into memory so I would like to get 10K or so at a time to batch into chunks of 64 or 128 (depending on model size). I am currently using rdd.sample() but I don't think that guarantees I will get all rows. Is there a better method to partition the data to make it more manageable so that I can write a generator function for getting batches? My code is below:

```
data_df = spark.read.parquet(PARQUET_FILE)
print(f'RDD Count: {data_df.count()}') # 6B+
data_sample = data_df.sample(True, 0.0000015).take(6400) 
sample_df = data_sample.toPandas()

def get_batch():
  for row in sample_df.itertuples():
    # TODO: put together a batch size of BATCH_SIZE
    yield row

for i in range(10):
    print(next(get_batch()))
```

Comment: Just a heads up your naming is wrong, that's not are rdd that's a dataframe.

Comment: Also I don't believe you have nothing to win on iterating over spark using pandas, it would be better if you read this in python  in chunks.

Comment: I changed the naming to reflect that it is a dataframe. I need the data as a Pandas dataframe for feeding into an existing model.

Comment: I would kindly ask why the question was down voted. I have spent a lot of time Googling for how to do this. If the answer is obvious or there is a documented/well understood mechanism, I would appreciate a link and I will apologize for the waste of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe spark let's you offset or paginate your data.

But you can add an index and then paginate over that, First:

```py
    from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
    data_df = spark.read.parquet(PARQUET_FILE)
    count = data_df.count()
    chunk_size = 10000

    # Just adding a column for the ids
    df_new_schema = data_df.withColumn('pres_id', lit(1))
    
    # Adding the ids to the rdd 
    rdd_with_index = data_df.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda (row,rowId): (list(row) + [rowId+1]))
    
    # Creating a dataframe with index
    df_with_index = spark.createDataFrame(rdd_with_index,schema=df_new_schema.schema)
    
    # Iterating into the chunks
    for page_num in range(0, count+1, chunk_size):
        initial_page = page_num*chunk_size
        final_page = initial_page + chunk_size 
        where_query = ('pres_id > {0} and pres_id <= {1}').format(initial_page,final_page)
        chunk_df = df_with_index.where(where_query).toPandas()
        train_on_batch(chunk_df) # <== Your function here
```

This is not optimal it will badly leverage spark because of the use of a pandas dataframe but will solve your problem.

Don't forget to drop the `id` if this affects your function.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
 from pyspark.sql import functions as F
 sample_dict = {}

 # Read the parquet file
 df = spark.read.parquet("parquet file")

 # add the partition_number as a column
 df = df.withColumn('partition_num', F.spark_partition_id())
 df.persist()

 total_partition = [int(row.partition_num) for row in 
 df.select('partition_num').distinct().collect()]

 for each_df in total_partition:
     sample_dict[each_df] = df.where(df.partition_num == each_df)
```

Comment: This worked for me, especially since i had a large parquet file