# How to save a Dataframe in batches in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to split a dataframe into chunks using the following code:

```
chunk = 50
id1 = 0
id2 = chunk
df = df.withColumn('id_tmp', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
c = df.count()
while id1 < c:
    stop_df = df.filter((df['id_tmp'] < id2) & (df['id_tmp'] >= id1))
    
    stop_df.write \
        .mode('overwrite')\
        .option("header", True) \
        .option("sep", "|") \
        .option('quoteAll', True) \
        .format("csv") \
        .save("filepath")


    id1 += chunk
    id2 += chunk
```

But it's only writing the first 50 rows (1st chunk) into csv.

What changes do I need to make to save other chunks as well?

Comment: I don't have a setup to test this with, but `.mode('overwrite')` looks wrong if you're trying to append to the file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the function `monotonically_increasing_id` doesn't generate consecutive numbers. From the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id.html):

> The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and
> unique, but not consecutive. The current implementation puts the partition ID in the upper 31 bits, and the record number within each partition in the lower 33 bits. ...

If we add `df.show()` to your code we can see this happening, it starts of OK but the next partition it jumps dramatically:

```
df = spark.range(0,90)
chunk = 50
id1 = 0
id2 = chunk
df = df.withColumn('id_tmp', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
df.show()


+---+-----------+
| id|     id_tmp|
+---+-----------+
|  0|          0|
|  1|          1|
|  2|          2|
|  3|          3|
|  4|          4|
|  5| 8589934592|
|  6| 8589934593|
|  7| 8589934594|
|  8| 8589934595|
|  9| 8589934596|
| 10| 8589934597|
| 11|17179869184|
| 12|17179869185|
| 13|17179869186|
| 14|17179869187|
| 15|17179869188|
| 16|25769803776|
| 17|25769803777|
| 18|25769803778|
| 19|25769803779|
+---+-----------+
```

If you need exact batch sizes you could use [row_number](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.row_number.html) over a window, but this window would need to include your complete df, making it inefficient. Could be ok for smaller dfs at the end of a data processing pipeline, or if you can partition by a column.

Some other solutions are discussed in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645256/how-do-you-get-batches-of-rows-from-spark-using-pyspark).
Finally, you probably want to use a different path for each batch, otherwise all data will be overwritten each time.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to achieve this using a new dataframe with an id that I've created locally.

##### Steps used

- Use the chunk size to determine the number of partitions
- Use the number of partitions to create a list/array with the partition number which will correspond to the ids.
- Create a list/array of ids which can map one to one with your existing dataframes ids
- Create new dataframe with the created partition list and matching id list
- Join to your existing dataframe
- Write using `partitionBy` on the partition number column

##### Code

Code for the above steps are as follows:

```py
chunk = 50

id = list(range(0,200))
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ... 199]
num_parts = int(len(id)/chunk)
# 4 chunks

# distribute it based on the chunks you need
part = list()
# [] empty list
for i in range(num_parts):
   for value in range(chunk):
     part.append(i)
# [0, 0, 0 ... 1, 1, 1, ...3, 3, 3]

part_data = [i for i in zip(id, part)]
# [(0, 0), (0, 1), .... (0, 49), (1, 50), (1, 51), .... (3, 199)]

part_df = spark.createDataFrame(part_data, ["id", "part"])
part_df.show(5, False)
# +---+----+
# |id |part|
# +---+----+
# |0  |0   |
# |1  |0   |
# |2  |0   |
# |3  |0   |
# |4  |0   |
# +---+----+
# only showing top 5 rows



df = spark.range(0,200)
df.show(5, False)
# +---+
# |id |
# +---+
# |0  |
# |1  |
# |2  |
# |3  |
# |4  |
# +---+
# only showing top 5 rows


new_df = df.join(part_df, "id")
new_df.show(5, False)
# +---+----+
# |id |part|
# +---+----+
# |0  |0   |
# |1  |0   |
# |2  |0   |
# |3  |0   |
# |4  |0   |
# +---+----+
# only showing top 5 rows


new_df.write.option("header", True).partitionBy("part").csv("so/test1")
# 4 x parts, each part 50 rows
```

##### Screenshot

The resulting folder structure is as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]